# Why can't display the kana by char array in C language on my computer?

Tags: c, windows

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int  main()
{
    char test[100] = "おおお\n";
    int len = strlen(test);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("%c", test[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the code doesn't display the kana「おおお」on my computer,
but the same code on my friend computer display the kana.
We all windows 10 OS,and the same japanese language.
Is there something wrong setting on my computer?

[image]

[and the printf is work good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXP8M.png)

Comment: Read http://utf8everywhere.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the "encoding" your editor (or browser, or whatever you are using) is set to.

Check that it is the same on the two computers (it may be UTF-8, UTF-16, JIS, ...) and remember that from a C point of view the result of `strlen("お")` is NOT 1.

Comment: Thank you for answering.Yes, our encoding is all same JIS,In JIS [お]have two byte,but char is one byte,my computer print the char one by one.We all confusing that.

Comment: @zei: "In JIS [お] has two byte" but yet you are attempting to print *one* byte at a time.

Comment: yes,but the same code print "おおお"on my friend's computer

Comment: Zei, same executable or same code compiled on different machines? By default "%c" should print only one byte but it is possible that some specific flag has to be used on your compiler to have a different behaviour. Which compiler are you (both) using?

Comment: Sorry I now realized that the problem is not in the code but in the console you're using. The C code has no other option than printing the two bytes of that kana, the point is that on your computer your console (a DOS prompt or a msys shell or something else) is set differently than the one of your friend. Try putting the output in a file and you'll see that they are the same on the two computers. It's the way your consol bheave that is different. (Please, let me know if I guessed righe. arigatō!)

Comment: Sorry for replying late.Yes,you are right @Remo.D,when i read from file ,it display kana good.I think it's some problem in my console,I don't know how to set it.When it print char one by one,It still different from my friend's console.BTW,print kana string is good.just problem of print char.